# Tag Wiki Popup does not show when editing a post

Tags: feature-request, edits, tag-wiki

Whenever I edit a post I also like to make sure that the necessary tags are present and that all tags present are appropriate.

Some tags, however are not obvious or ambiguous. Luckily most of those tags already have a good Tag Wiki that tells us how it should be used (example: [check](/questions/tagged/check), which seems to be about a C testing library).

When I edit a question, however, I can't get to that information, unless I *either*

- re-enter an existing tag and wait for the auto-complete popup *or*
- I cancel editing and mouse-over the existing tags.

This seems needlessly complicated, why doesn't just hovering over the tags show the Tag Wiki, just as it does in the normal view?

Comment: How often is this really an issue? When are you consistently editing if you don't know what the tags of a post mean?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII: I just had this problem with [tag:check] and occasionally see it when new users apply tags that they *think* do apply, but are actually about some other framework.